# Реализовать checkBox в роли "запомнить"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Привет всем!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать checkBox так же, как на программах и сайтах, там, где нужно произвести вход по имени и паролю, там всегда есть функция запомнить, чтобы при следующем входе программа уже не спрашивала имя и пароль.

Я изначально делал так: кликнул по checkBox, и образовался простой текст файл с именем, потом при следующем входе прога проверяла, если есть такой файл-то - не спрашивала пароль. Но здесь на форуме я вычитал, что при уже готовой проинсталированной программе у меня не будет доступа для записи в директории bin или дебаг,
а писать код, чтобы файл сохранялся в другом месте, я еще не могу сообразить, как это делается.
Да и, разумеется, есть правильный подход к этому вопросу.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft рекомендует следующий способ сериализации:
 1. Выбираете пункт Settings в Solution.
 2. Создаете переменную необходимого типа (в вашем случае bool).

[image]

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.IsRemember;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.IsRemember = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

[Пример приложения](https://bitbucket.org/beliy26rus/rememberapp/src).

[Еще способы сериализации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/et91as27.aspx).

Comment: @beliy26rus Спасибо за ответ. Только вы не могли бы написать то, что подчеркнули на картинке с правой стороны, а то я не могу разглядеть.

Comment: IsRemember название вашей переменной

Comment: @beliy26rus . Спасибо, правда, я спрашивал, что с права написано :) ну не важно, я понял, что Settings

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос здесь не в checkbox'е, конкретная реализация в интерфейсе — дело десятое. Вам стоит подумать о том, как будет инсталлирована программа и где она будет хранить данные.

Если вы собираетесь хранить данные локально, это стоит делать в подкаталоге `%APPDATA%` с именем, как у вашей программы (по хорошему, конечно, вашей *компании*, но это, как я понимаю, в будущем). Данные будут доступны, понятно, только текущему пользователю ОС (ну и администратору, разумеется) — и это правильно.

По поводу хранения пароля, всё сложно. Если вы кладёте пароль в открытом виде, это «приглашение» украсть его. С другой стороны, даже если вы будете шифровать пароль, надёжного хранения пароля на локальной машине добиться вовсе невозможно, т. к. если ваша программа может его прочитать и расшифровать, а машина скомпроментирована, то и злоумышленник точно так же сможет. Поэтому возможно стоит шифровать, но не обещать никакой «безопасности» пользователю.

Хорошим компромиссом является хранение только имени пользователя, но не пароля. На то он и пароль, что известен только человеку.

Comment: @VladD
Вся информация о человеке хранится на удаленной базе MySQL, ну, в принципе это не важно. Как я делал изначально, так просто пустой фаил сохранял без записи, просто потом решил еще и имя писать - да без пароля.

Comment: Если пароль захотят украсть, то украдут, даже если вы его зашифруете, через любой рефлектор можно будет посмотреть ваш алгоритм шифрования.  Храните только логин, так же как и галочку "сохранять не сохранять".

Comment: @beliy26rus
если я у вас спрашиваю, такие глупые вопросы,как и куда записывать файл. То понятное дело что у меня не такой уровень знаний чтобы делать сверх супер проги чтобы кому-то захотелось вскрыть её. Я учу C# совместно делаю проект. так как я не могу учить и не применить новый материал на деле. чтоб-бы сразу было понять что как и зачем. уровень у меня очень слаб. даже то что вы мне сказали (это стоит делать в подкаталоге %APPDATA% с именем) в принципе мне это ничего не говорит. Просто теперь я буду знать куда копать дальше

Comment: Тогда не парьтесь и храните и логин и пароль, как написано в первом ответе. А дальше копайте в сторону Isolated Storage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx